# Throw http exception (Unauthorized) from Application_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-403, httpexception

I am trying to throw this row from Global asax Application_Error

```
throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Forbidden");
```

But for some reason I am getting 200 and not 401 in the browser, do you know why?

**Update:**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Forbidden");
}
```

Comment: Are you have forms auth. enabled in web.config? If you have forms authentication enabled in web.config then you may get this behavior.

Comment: @Mark , Thanks but no I dont.

Comment: Plz post your Application_Error

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
     Server.ClearError();
 }
```

However, instead of setting status code in Global.asax, you should apply authentication and authorization in web.config